# Have a problem with keyExtractor - Warning unique ''key''

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in react native , just starting to learn.
I have a FlatList that contain data from array like this one:

```
const friends = [
        { name: 'Friend #1', age: '26', },
        { name: 'Friend #2', age: '31' },
        { name: 'Friend #3', age: '34' },
];
```

In the method that return the FlatList I'm added keyExtractor:

```
return (
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={friend => friend.name}
            data={friends}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return ([
                    <Text style={styles.itemView}>{item.name} - Age {item.age}</Text>
                ]
                );
            }} />
    );
```

Still have a warning:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s
```

Comment: Did you try searching the web for that error string? It should return relevant information.

Comment: Try not to use an array inside the render function. Something like this: `return (<Text>...</Text>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you nested `Text` element inside array

Change it like this:

```js
    <FlatList
            keyExtractor={friend => friend.name}
            data={friends}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                    <Text style={styles.itemView}>{item.name} - Age {item.age}</Text>
                );
            }} 
    />
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-banzai-sjobt)

Comment: Thanks @bravemaster

Comment: You can upvote and accept my answer if mine was helpful :)

Comment: I tried , but my rating is under 15=[ It's my first question here, so...